# Formula in Cross-sheet reference not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm using excel 2010 and currently have 2 sheets named **Planner** and **Chart** without the quotes.
In **Planner** cell P6, the value is 20.
In **Chart**, I have a formula`=IF('Planner'!P6=20, 81, 0)` but it keeps returning 0 instead of 81. What is the problem?

Edit: The formula `=IF(P6=20, 81, 0)`works when it's in **Planner**.

Comment: Is your source cell actually a number? if this works `IF(VALUE('Planner'!P6)=20, 81, 0)` then your cell is text

Comment: What is the output of =Planner!P6 in the Chart sheet?  Also, what happens if you use the code =IF(Planner!P6=20, 81, 0) on the Planner sheet (it should give the same results).

Comment: @brettdj The format of cell P6 is number, I deleted it and retyped it to confirm that it does not have a decimal value
@Jonathan The output is 0 on `=Planner!P6` and yes, =IF(Planner!P6=20, 81, 0) gives the same results whereby it's still a blank cell

Comment: Does this work `=IF(INT(VALUE('Planner'!P6))=20, 81, 0)` - tests for both an integer 20 and ensures it is numeric

Comment: @user3902522, that should only be a solution if the cell itself is not numeric. You may need to go back and check this if you want root cause analysis.

Comment: In Excel 2003, deleting and re-typing a character does not change the cell format.  To do that, you can right-click the cell and choose "Format Cells...", then select "Number" on the left side.  That may differ slightly in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

On a brand new woorkbook under Excel 2012, that works fine.

So, my first suggestion is to actually check the *content* of the `Planner!P6` cell. If it's something like `'20`, then that's a text element and the `if` statement will be false.

It should be a *numeric* result, something like `20` or `=20` or `=blah` where the result of the `blah` expression is a numeric 20.

You should also check that the *formatting* of the cell isn't deceiving you, such as if the value is `20.001` but formatted to zero decimal places.

If necessary, actually *put* `=20` into the cell temporarily to see if that fixes it. If so, the original contents are not what you think.

---

The next step after that will be to, as I have done, create a brand new work book with just the two sheets, renamed to `Planner` and `Chart`.

Then, in `Planner!P6`, enter `20` and, in `Chart!A1`, enter your formua `=IF('Planner'!P6=20, 81, 0)`.

If that doesn't work, then either your Excel is broken or there's some default in new workbooks that is preventing cross-sheet references from working properly (which would be news to me).

If it works, then there's something *else* wrong with your initial workbook.

That should at least narrow it down a bit.

Comment: When it's in planner it reflects 81 meaning that P6=20. The problem is that it doesn't reflect the same in Chart